# node--view--[machine-name] ignored in production

Tags: 8, theming

On my development, local site (twig debug enable, cache disable), I create node template for specific view block by Drupal suggestions:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'node' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * node--view--promoted-content--block-promoted-content.html.twig
   x node--view--promoted-content.html.twig
   * node--7398--teaser.html.twig
   * node--7398.html.twig
   * node--news--teaser.html.twig
   * node--news.html.twig
   * node--teaser.html.twig
   * node.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/anime24/templates/content/node--view--promoted-content.html.twig' -->
```

And exactly: `node--view--promoted-content.html.twig`, and all seams to work perfectly:

[image]

But when I move site to production (standard hosting, disable twig debug, enable cache), Drupal ignore my `node--view--[machine-name].twig.html` templates, and load `node--teaser.html.twig`:

[image]

It looks like some weird cache issue, because, when I reload one of Block with AJAX filter, it loads an proper twig template:

[image]

And after click:

[image]

Has anyone encountered this error and is able to help me with the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you flush all cache?

Comment: Yes. I try default cache cleaner, devel cache cleaner, I remove files from `sites/default/files/php/twig` and clear database `cache_` tables. Drush unfortunately not working on my server.

Comment: and you have double checked that the file is inside your active theme's /templates folder and that the file in the server does contain the correct HTML code? Could be a rare case that your FTP is not overriding the file.